# TinyMCE audio source wrong formatting

Tags: tinymce, html5-audio

I'm trying to make  work with TinyMCE, but I'm having a serious problem with the sources.
What I need is to get this code:

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="file.mp3" />
  <source src="file.ogg" />
</audio>
```

but TinyMCE changes this to

```
<audio controls="controls" width="300" height="32" preload="none" src="file.mp3" />
  <source src="file.ogg" />
</audio>
```

This makes the code break in Firefox.

I've tried to change TinyMCE options. Actually I'm using the following:

```
tinyMCE.init({
  mode : "exact",
  theme : 'advanced',
  plugins : 'pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,advlist',
  media_strict: false,
  theme_advanced_toolbar_location : 'top',
  theme_advanced_toolbar_align : 'left',
  extended_valid_elements : 'script[language|type]',
  theme_advanced_resizing : true,
  content_css : './sites/default/css/styles.css',
  theme_advanced_statusbar_location : 'bottom',
  theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
  theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
  theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen,|,attribs",

  // ADDING THE FOLLOWING DID NOT CHANGE THE RESULT
  cleanup_on_startup: false,
  trim_span_elements: false,
  verify_html: false,
  cleanup: false,
  convert_urls: false
});
```